# R: Counting the Frequencies of Coin Flips

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I simulated this dataset which contains 1000 coin flips - then I calculated the number of "2  Flip Sequences":

```
Coin <- c('H', 'T')
Results = sample(Coin,1000, replace = TRUE)
My_Data = data.frame(id = 1:1000, Results)



Pairs = data.frame(first = head(My_Data$Results, -1), second = tail(My_Data$Results, -1))
Final = as.data.frame(table(Pairs))

  first second Freq
1     H      H  255
2     T      H  245
3     H      T  246
4     T      T  253
```

I am curious - **is it possible to extend the above code for "3 Flip Sequences"?**

For example - I tried modifying parts of the code to see how the results change (and hoped to stumble across the correct way to write this code):

```
# First Attempt
Pairs = data.frame(first = head(My_Data$Results, -1), second  = head(My_Data$Results, -1) , third = tail(My_Data$Results, -1))
Final = as.data.frame(table(Pairs))

  first second third Freq
1     H      H     H  255
2     T      H     H  245
3     H      T     H    0
4     T      T     H    0
5     H      H     T    0
6     T      H     T    0
7     H      T     T  246
8     T      T     T  253

# Second Attempt
Pairs = data.frame(first = head(My_Data$Results, -1), second  = tail(My_Data$Results, -1) , third = tail(My_Data$Results, -1))
Final = as.data.frame(table(Pairs))

  first second third Freq
1     H      H     H  255
2     T      H     H    0
3     H      T     H    0
4     T      T     H  245
5     H      H     T  246
6     T      H     T    0
7     H      T     T    0
8     T      T     T  253
```

I am not sure which of these options are correct?

- In general, I am looking to understand the logic as to how I can adapt the above code for an "arbitrary number of coin flips" (e.g. "4 flip sequences", "5 flip sequences", etc.)
- Also, this might not be the most efficient way to calculate these frequencies - I would also be interested in learning about other ways that might be more efficient ( e.g. as the overall size of the data increases).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be helpful to work with strings.

```
coin <- c("H", "T")
results <- sample(coin, 1000, replace = TRUE)
```

Then to get sequence counts (assuming overlapping sequences also count) for triples, we could do something like:

```
triples <- table(
  sapply(
    1:(length(results) - 3),
    function(i) sprintf(
      "%s%s%s",
      results[i],
      results[i + 1],
      results[i + 2]
    )
  )
)
```

which gives me something like:

```
HHH HHT HTH HTT THH THT TTH TTT 
132 129 138 115 129 124 116 114
```

This idea could be generalized fairly easily, for example:

```
n_sequences <- function(n, results) {
  helper <- function(i, n) if (n < 1) "" else sprintf(
    "%s%s", 
    helper(i, n - 1), 
    results[i + n - 1]
  )
  result <- data.frame(
    table(
      sapply(
        1:(length(results) - n + 1),
        function(i) helper(i, n)
      )
    )
  )
  colnames(result) <- c("Sequence", "Frequency")
  result
}
```

For example:

```
n_sequences(5, results)
```

Gives me something like:

```
   Sequence Frequency
1     HHHHH        34
2     HHHHT        31
3     HHHTH        36
4     HHHTT        31
5     HHTHH        35
6     HHTHT        36
7     HHTTH        20
8     HHTTT        37
9     HTHHH        35
10    HTHHT        34
11    HTHTH        41
12    HTHTT        27
13    HTTHH        27
14    HTTHT        24
15    HTTTH        34
16    HTTTT        30
17    THHHH        31
18    THHHT        36
19    THHTH        36
20    THHTT        26
21    THTHH        34
22    THTHT        32
23    THTTH        31
24    THTTT        27
25    TTHHH        32
26    TTHHT        28
27    TTHTH        25
28    TTHTT        31
29    TTTHH        33
30    TTTHT        31
31    TTTTH        30
32    TTTTT        20
```

Comment: @ Richard Ambler: I tried to apply your function in this question and I think one of the final sequences wasn't picked up. If you have time, could you please take a look at it? Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74765675/r-counting-the-frequency-of-n-consecutive-sequences

Comment: @stats_noob Good catch. I went all the way to the end but one. I blame R's choice to index from 1 instead of 0! ;) I hope it's fixed now!

Answer (score 1):

You could first `cut` along 3 + 1 breaks, `split` it along the levels. The `interaction` can now be `table`d to get the `res`ult.

```
My_Data$cut3 <-  cut(seq_len(nrow(My_Data)), seq.int(1, nrow(My_Data), length.out=3 + 1), include.lowest=TRUE)

(res <- interaction(split(My_Data$Results, My_Data$cut3)) |> table() |> as.data.frame())

#    Var1 Freq
# 1 H.H.H   51
# 2 T.H.H   58
# 3 H.T.H   43
# 4 T.T.H   49
# 5 H.H.T   38
# 6 T.H.T   51
# 7 H.T.T   64
# 8 T.T.T   46
```

To get the desired output, we can `strsplit` `Var1`.

```
strsplit(as.character(res$Var1), '\\.') |> do.call(what=rbind) |>
  cbind.data.frame(res$Freq) |> setNames(c('first', 'second', 'third', 'Freq'))
#   first second third Freq
# 1     H      H    H   51
# 2     T      H    H   58
# 3     H      T    H   43
# 4     T      T    H   49
# 5     H      H    T   38
# 6     T      H    T   51
# 7     H      T    T   64
# 8     T      T    T   46
```

**Note,** that `nrow` of your data should be divisible by 3.

### Edit

To generalize, we may write a small function.

```
f <- \(x, n) {
  ct <-  cut(seq_len(nrow(x)), seq.int(1L, nrow(x), length.out=n + 1L), include.lowest=TRUE)
  res <- interaction(split(x$Results, ct)) |> table() |> as.data.frame()
  strsplit(as.character(res$Var1), '\\.') |> do.call(what=rbind) |>
    cbind.data.frame(res$Freq) |> setNames(c(LETTERS[seq_len(n)], 'Freq'))
}

f(My_Data, 4)
#    A B C D Freq
# 1  H H H H   13
# 2  T H H H   25
# 3  H T H H   18
# 4  T T H H   17
# 5  H H T H   18
# 6  T H T H   15
# 7  H T T H   21
# 8  T T T H   24
# 9  H H H T   26
# 10 T H H T   15
# 11 H T H T   16
# 12 T T H T   18
# 13 H H T T   22
# 14 T H T T   18
# 15 H T T T   10
# 16 T T T T   24
```

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
My_Data <- data.frame(id=1:1200, Results=sample(c('H', 'T'), 1200, replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! Suppose now I want to look at "4 Flips" - is this modification correct?

Comment: My_Data$cut4 <-  cut(seq_len(nrow(My_Data)), seq.int(1, nrow(My_Data), length.out=4 + 1), include.lowest=TRUE)

Comment: (res <- interaction(split(My_Data$Results, My_Data$cut4)) |> table() |> as.data.frame())

Comment: strsplit(as.character(res$Var1), '\\.') |> do.call(what=rbind) |>
  cbind.data.frame(res$Freq) |> setNames(c('first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'Freq'))

Comment: @stats_noob Instead of `LETTERS` you could use a vector of ordinal numbers text, `c('first', 'second', ..., 'nth')[seq_len(n)]`.

Comment: Hmm. I assumed, for example, the sequence HHTH contains two sequences of three: HHT and HTH. You appear to be breaking the sequence into groups of three and then counting the sequences (i.e. ignoring overlap). I guess the context of the problem determines which is the correct approach. Nice post!

Answer (score 1):

A slightly generalized solution with tidyverse tools. Change the `sets` variable for longer or shorter sequences.

```
coin <- c("H", "T")
sets <- 4
rolls <- 10000

results <- sample(coin, sets * rolls, rep = TRUE)

named_results <- purrr::map_chr(
    0:(rolls - 1),
    ~ paste0(results[(sets * .x + 1):(sets * .x + sets)],
        collapse = ""
    )
)

dplyr::count(tibble::tibble(x = named_results), x)
```

with output

```
# A tibble: 16 x 2
   x         n
   <chr> <int>
 1 HHHH    629
 2 HHHT    627
 3 HHTH    638
 4 HHTT    599
 5 HTHH    602
 6 HTHT    633
 7 HTTH    596
 8 HTTT    661
 9 THHH    631
10 THHT    589
11 THTH    633
12 THTT    647
13 TTHH    660
14 TTHT    637
15 TTTH    623
16 TTTT    595
```

`sets = 8` would give something like

```
# A tibble: 256 x 2
   x            n
   <chr>    <int>
 1 HHHHHHHH    37
 2 HHHHHHHT    36
 3 HHHHHHTH    43
 4 HHHHHHTT    35
 5 HHHHHTHH    38
 6 HHHHHTHT    27
 7 HHHHHTTH    32
 8 HHHHHTTT    28
 9 HHHHTHHH    33
10 HHHHTHHT    38
# ... with 246 more rows
```